# How to define a private grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, private

When I defined a grid in xaml and use the x:Name such as the code below,the grid seems to be "internal".I can use it just with the x:Name--'testGrid' in the same project.

```
    <Grid x:Name="testGrid"></Grid>
```

I mean that why don't define the Grid as "private",since it is "internal" then we can add/remove children to it or even can change its behaviour?Is that safe for a "sealed" class?

Thanks for your time and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FieldModifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) property.

**Edit**

After reading the documentation carefully, there is no way to make a field *private*. It's either *public* (Public) or *internal* (NonPublic).

So this do not answer your question...

Anyway, you (or your team) are supposed to not intentionally mess up with your own classes, so maybe *internal*, while not perfect, is "good enough"?